# Count the number of children which have a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to count the number of div elements with the attribute `style='display:none;'`. As you can see from the code below

```
<div class="parent-class">
 <div id="child1" class="line-content"> TEST1 </div>

 <div id="child2" class="line-content"> TEST2 </div>

 <div id="child3" class="line-content"> TEST3 </div>

 <div id="child4" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST4 </div>

 <div id="child5" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST5 </div>

 <div id="child6" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST6 </div>
</div>
```

we have 3 such div elements. I would like to count how many div elements on the parent with class `parent-class` with that attribute. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just use `alert($('div:hidden').length)`

Comment: console.log($('.parent-class  div[style="display:none;"]').length);

Comment: @SudhakarAyyar thats not a very good solution. First attribute selectors will be slow and second as soon as you add another style it breaks

Comment: @Jamiec ,He clearly mention the element must have the attribute like this style='display:none;'.so this is the correct way to get otherwise he can use $('.parent-class div[style*="display:none;"]').length ...(if suppose #child1{display:none} then ur code will be wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know how to count the number of div element who has
>   the attribute style='display:none;'

Use `filter`

```
$( "div.parent-class > div" ).filter( function( i,v ){ 
   return v.style.display == "none"; 
}).length;
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = $( "div.parent-class > div" ).filter( function( i,v ){ 
   return v.style.display == "none"; 
}).length;

console.log( output );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-class">
  <div id="child1" class="line-content"> TEST1 </div>

  <div id="child2" class="line-content"> TEST2 </div>

  <div id="child3" class="line-content"> TEST3 </div>

  <div id="child4" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST4 </div>

  <div id="child5" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST5 </div>

  <div id="child6" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST6 </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

If you want to check the hidden elements (**different from checking which element has display:none**), then check this demo to see the difference.

```js
var output = $( "div" ).filter( function( i,v ){ 
   return v.style.display == "none"; 
}).length;

console.log( "output with filter - " + output );

var output = $( "div:hidden" ).length;

console.log( "output with hidden - " + output );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-class">
  <div id="child1" class="line-content"> TEST1 </div>
  <div id="child2" class="line-content"> TEST2 </div>
  <div id="child3" class="line-content"> TEST3 </div>
  <div id="child4" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST4 </div>
  <div id="child5" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> 
    TEST5 
    <div  style="display:none;">
        
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child6" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> 
      TEST5 
    <div>        
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `*` filter? You can narrow that down much more using `div.parent-class > div` and it'll be much quicker.

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks :), but I will stick to `div` alone since OP hasn't specifically asked for those `div` which are child of `div` with class as `parent-class`.

Comment: It's *literally in the question*: `I would like to count how many div elements on the parent with class parent-class with that attribute`

Comment: @Jamiec My bad, I only saw the top part.

Answer (score 4):

Reference:- [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Do like below:-

```
console.log($('.line-content:hidden').length);
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
console.log($('.line-content:hidden').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-class">
 <div id="child1" class="line-content"> TEST1 </div>

 <div id="child2" class="line-content"> TEST2 </div>

 <div id="child3" class="line-content"> TEST3 </div>

 <div id="child4" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST4 </div>

 <div id="child5" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST5 </div>

 <div id="child6" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST6 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is looking for *I would like to know how to count the number of div element who has the attribute style='display:none;'* Check the second demo in my answer to see the difference.

Comment: I guess it is relevant to OP's use case but that's said, `:hidden` pseudo selector isn't just checking for `display` property

Comment: Ive removed my upvote on this. Using an attribute selector is a very brittle solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$('div:hidden').length` or `$('.line-content:hidden').length`

Comment: You should check that all of the matched div are children of the `parent-class`. Otherwise it would match anything hidden regardless of the structure.

Comment: It's suitable in this given code. @LoïcFaure-Lacroix

Comment: Yes but real life example aren't always the snippet of code written in the question but a minimal sample of code that allow reproducing an error. Good answer should be more generic than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jQuery for this :

```
$(".parent-class > div:hidden").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code,

```
var count = $('div.parent-class > div:hidden').length;
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var len = $('div[style]').length;
console.log(len);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-class">
 <div id="child1" class="line-content"> TEST1 </div>

 <div id="child2" class="line-content"> TEST2 </div>

 <div id="child3" class="line-content"> TEST3 </div>

 <div id="child4" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST4 </div>

 <div id="child5" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST5 </div>

 <div id="child6" class="line-content" style="display:none;"> TEST6 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use:
    jQuery('parent-class > div[style*="display: none"]').length;